Use functions as parameter inside next.config.js
I need to pass a function to a library from the configuration.
I tried to inserting a function in the next.config.js like:
{
  ...
  loadAsset: async function (assetPath) {
      ...
  },
  ...
}

This works in my development environment, but it doesn't work on Vercel because config is serialized at build time.
What other ways could I set a function in the configuration to make it accessible to an external library?
